# Locus of right circular cone vertices resulting from constant conic intersection

Tags: geometry, conic-sections, solid-geometry, locus

Five points  on $(x-y)$ plane  $ (x1,y1), (x2,y2),... (x5,y5)$ defining a common conic intersection curve $C$ are obtained by section with variably inclined right circular cones i.e.,variable vertex $V$ position.

[image: Same Intrxn of Cones]

Find locus $L$ of all vertices $V.$

*Background:*

We have    $ \epsilon$= eccentricity , $\gamma=$ semi-vertical angle of cone, $\alpha =$ angle to symmetry axis  and since

$$\epsilon=\dfrac{\cos\gamma}{\cos\alpha},$$

the above relation implies that that every conic section is associated uniquely with an intersected right circular cone upto

- scale
- rotation around axis of symmetry and
- translation

Special case : If $C$ is a circle then $L$ is the common axis of symmetry of each cone.

Thanks in advance for pointers to vertex locus finding.

Comment: I vaguely recall seeing this problem described in one of the old geometry books. I think it was in Somerville’s book.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the given conic is either an ellipse or a hyperbola, vertex $V$ of the cone must lie on the plane perpendicular to the plane of the conic and passing through its foci.

Let $A$ and $B$ be the endpoints of the transverse axis of the conic, $V$ the cone vertex, and $2u$ the aperture angle of the cone. Let then $P$ be any point on the ellipse and $H$ its projection onto $AB$. A plane through $P$, perpendicular to the axis of the cone, intersects the cone along a circle $A'B'P$ (see diagram below), where $A'$ and $B'$ lie on plane $VAB$.

By the intersecting chords theorem we know that $PH^2=A'H\cdot B'H$. But, on the other hand, we have by similitude: 
$$
A'H:AH=BC:AB,
\quad\hbox{that is:}\quad
A'H={BC\over AB}\cdot AH;
$$
$$
B'H:BH=AD:AB,
\quad\hbox{that is:}\quad
B'H={AD\over AB}\cdot BH.
$$

If we set $n=VA$, $m=VB$ and $2a=AB$, the above formulas can be written as 
$$
A'H={m\sin u\over a}\cdot AH,
\quad
B'H={n\sin u\over a}\cdot BH,
$$
and inserting these into the formula for $PH^2$ we get:
$$
PH^2={mn\sin^2 u\over a^2}\,AH\cdot BH.
$$
If $H$ is a focus of the conic, then $PH={b^2/a}$ is the semi-latus rectum,
while $AH\cdot BH=|a^2-c^2|=b^2$ (as usual $2b$ is the length of the conjugate axis and $2c$ is the distance between foci) and from the above equation we get:
$$
\tag{1}
mn={b^2\over \sin^2 u}.
$$
Another equation for $m$ and $n$ can be found from the cosine rule applied to triangle $AVB$:
$$
\tag{2}
m^2+n^2\mp2mn\cos2u=4a^2,
$$
where sign $-$ must be taken for an ellipse ($\angle AVB=2u$) and sign $+$ for a hyperbola ($\angle AVB=\pi-2u$).

[image]

If the conic is an ellipse one obtains from $(1)$ and $(2)$ 
$$(m-n)^2=4(a^2-b^2),$$ 
that is the difference of the distances of $V$ from $A$ and $B$ is constant.
The locus of $V$ is then a hyperbola, having its foci at the vertices of the ellipse and semi-major axis $\sqrt{a^2-b^2}$. This hyperbola thus passes through the foci of the ellipse.

If the conic is a hyperbola you get instead 
$$(m+n)^2=4(a^2+b^2)$$ 
and the locus of $V$  is an ellipse having its foci at the vertices of the hyperbola and semi-major axis $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$. This ellipse thus passes through the foci of the hyperbola.

Finally, if the conic is a parabola of  vertex $A$ and semi-latus rectum $p$ 
one gets from a similar reasoning:
$$
AV=n={p\over2\sin^2u}.
$$
From that it follows that the distance of vertex $V$ from the plane of the parabola is 
$$VK=n\sin2u=p\cot u,$$ 
while the distance from the projection of $V$ on that plane to the focus of the parabola is
$$KF=n\cos2u+p/2={p\over2}\cot^2u.$$ 
Hence $KF=VK^2/(2p)$ and the vertex thus lies on a a parabola, equal to the given parabola and having its vertex at the focus of the latter.

We can summarise the above results as follows:

> the locus of $V$ is a conic section, having center and transverse axis
>   in common with the given conic but lying in an orthogonal plane, with
>   eccentricity reciprocal to that of the given conic and vertices at the
>   foci of the given conic.

You can see below an example: the green ellipse on plane x-y has vertices $A$, $B$, foci $F$, $G$ and eccentricity $1/\sqrt2$. The locus of the vertex $V_1$ of any cone intercepting the ellipse is the pink hyperbola on plane x-z, with vertices $F$, $G$, foci $A$, $B$ and eccentricity $\sqrt2$. Conversely, the ellipse is the locus of the vertex $V_2$ of any cone intercepting the hyperbola. Note also that the axes of the cones are tangent to the locus where the vertex lies.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. It will be very nice to be able to see Geogebra  3D images e.g. with eccentricities (section, vertex locus) = $(\sqrt 2, 1/\sqrt 2),\,(1/\sqrt 2,\sqrt 2)$

Comment: I'll see if I can recover the GeoGebra file I used for that old answer and modify it.

Comment: Hi, can you help me here? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4182690/an-ellipse-has-foci-at-1-1-and-2-1-and-tangent-xy-5-0-find-the-p